# Delete event from front end

Tags: events, solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar, calendar

I am using [Solspace Calendar](https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/) plugin where front end user can add/edit events. Is there any functionality so that user can delete an event from front-end?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there currently isn't a built-in way for this to work. It is on the feature requests list for Calendar for future consideration, however.